# R: Nomear vetor dentro de um for

Tags: r

Estou fazendo um `for` em meu script, mas na ultima linha quando executo `models$i`, eu precisava que esse `i` fosse o valor do meu `i` do `for`, teria como fazer?

```
for(i in x){
    maxit <- as.integer(1000000)
    algoritmo <- neuralnet(dados2016[,5] ~ dados2016[,4],
    data <- dados2016, hidden=i ,threshold=1, stepmax=maxit)
    teste <- compute(algoritmo, dados2017[,4])

    precos$weight[] <- NA
    precos$weight[] <- if(dados2017[,4] < teste$net.result[,1], 1, 0)
    models$i <- bt.run.share(precos, clean.signal=T)
}
```

Comment: Teu código não é reproduzível. Por exemplo, não sabemos o que é `x`, de quais pacotes saíram os comandos `neuralnet` e similares e qual o output do comando `bt.run.share`. Também não sabemos qual o erro que aparece quando o código é executado. Recomendo editar a pergunta, de forma que alguém que queira te ajudar consiga copiar e colar o teu código para executar em seu próprio computador.

Comment: Se vc está querendo acessar a coluna i, o correto é models[ ,i]

Comment: Provavelmente você tem que acessar com `[[`: `models[[i]]`

Answer (score 1):

Esse objeto `models` deve ser uma lista. Você pode descobrir fazendo `typeof(models)`.
Mesmo que ele seja um `data.frame`, ele também será uma lista (Exemplo: `typeof(mtcars)`).

Se o objeto é uma lista, você pode acessar os elementos usando o operador `$`. 
Mas isso não aceita strings como inputs. Exemplo:

```
x <- "cyl"
mtcars$x
```

Uma forma de acessar elementos de uma lista pelo nome é usar a construção `[[]]`.
Com isso, você pode usar:

```
mtcars[[x]]
```

A mesma coisa pode ser feita para alterar objetos em um for.

```
for(i in colnames(mtcars)){
  mtcars[[i]] <- mtcars[[i]]/2
}
mtcars
```